# Compare cells then output based on value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to compare two ranges on different sheets within the same workbook.

sheet 1
[image]

sheet 2
[image]

If they are the same then copy a value from sheet 1 to sheet 2, five cells to the right of the compared value.

```
Sub compare_paste()

    Dim cell, cell2, revenue As Range.Value
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim sheet1, sheet2 As Worksheet
    Dim temp, lastName As String

    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

    Set sheet1 = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sheet2 = wbk.Sheets("Sheet2")

    For Each cell In sheet1.Range("a1:a" & Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row)
        lastName = cell.Value
        Set revenue = cell.Offset(0, 7)
        For Each cell2 In sheet2.Range("a:a" & Range("a").End(xlDown).Row)
            If lastName = cell2.Range Then
                revenue.Value = cell2.Offset(0, 7).Value
            End If
        Next cell2

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are going for. This can be done it other ways, but I am just seeing your method through.

Please note the important differences between how we declared variables. Also, your second range set was incorrect. Lastly, this has been updated to determine the last row from the bottom of the range instead of the top.

```
Sub Compare()

Dim WS1 As Worksheet: Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim WS2 As Worksheet: Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHeet2")

Dim LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long, WS1_Cell As Range, WS2_Cell As Range

LR1 = WS1.Range("A" & WS1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LR2 = WS2.Range("A" & WS2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each WS1_Cell In WS1.Range("A1:A" & LR1)
    For Each WS2_Cell In WS2.Range("A1:A" & LR2)
        If WS1_Cell = WS2_Cell Then
            WS1_Cell.Offset(, 7).Value = WS2_Cell.Offset(, 7).Value
        End If
    Next WS2_Cell
Next WS1_Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: yeah i tried inserting the revised code but it gets rid of that value and does not appear 5 cells to the right on sheet 2

Comment: I may have the sheets switched around. Can you read the code and let me know? What sheet should be changed here? Sheet1 or Sheet2? I can't help if you don't provide more specific examples of what is not working.

Comment: very valid point. it is clearing sheet ones value (f1) and nothing is appearing on sheet 2 (f4). in this case f1 should have ben copied in sheet1 and pasted in f4 on sheet 2 based on the comparison.

Comment: So swap my middle statement around accordingly :). All variables I used are using `1` and `2` which refer to sheets `1` and `2`.

Comment: awesome it worked last thing i am doing is running what happens if it tries the comparison and it doesn't work i want it to run this code.